# Extract the XML into Excel

Tags: xml, excel, xml-parsing

Can some one help me how to extract the below attributes to an excel file ?
If cannot done by Excel , what is the best way to do this ?

```
 <Job
  JOB_NAME="Vinoth"
  Time ="11:30"
 Date = "20150714">
</Job>
<Job
 JOB_NAME="Kumar"
 Time ="12:30"
Date = "20150715">
</Job>
```

Comment: You haven't told us _how_ you want the XML content to be extracted.  So, what do you want to appear in your Excel spreadsheet?

Comment: Hi , I want the JOB_NAME , TIme and Date as column and the respective values under that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that the XML *fragment* you posted isn't a complete XML document.  To make it a complete XML document you will need to wrap it with `<xml>` tags like this:

```
<xml>
    <Job JOB_NAME="Vinoth" Time ="11:30" Date = "20150714" />
    <Job JOB_NAME="Kumar" Time ="12:30" Date = "20150715" />
</xml>
```

Save this file as `input.xml` in a location where you can find it again later.

I followed the [official Microsoft documentation](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Map-XML-elements-to-cells-in-an-XML-Map-ddb23edf-f5c5-4fbf-b736-b3bf977a0c53) on how to use the XML Import feature under the Developer tab.  To make a long story short, you have to configure Excel to show the Developer tab on the top.  Once you have done this, you should see the following on the top of your screen:

[image]

Click the `Import` button under `XML`.  This will prompt you with a dialogue box where you can specify an input file.  Choose the file you saved above and specify a location where you want the data to go.  Excel will tell you that it wants to use a default schema because you did not provide one.  This is acceptable for your problem, but you should also realize that XML documents typically have an XSD schema file which defines how they should behave.

After the import your spreadsheet should look something like this:

[image]